# How can i split a captured column into 3 groups using regular expressions?

Tags: .net, regex

I am capturing a certain column of data, and i need to separate that one column into three different group captures using regular expressions. I have searched google and can only find this done using Java or some other code.

using the output below:

```
common: "mortalkombat_sonia_rules_abc," player: "Mortal Kombat,"    22-May-    22 
Test1   Test2   Type1   Type2   Type3   X   Y   HOR1    VER1    Data1         Error1         
Whitea   ab-1    abcr0201    222 22  -222    -22 -222    -22 2   2   Testing     
Whiteb   ab-1    abcr0201    222 22  -222    -22 -222    -22 2   2   Testing     
greya    ab-1    abcf0402    222 2   -222    -22 -222    -22 2   2   Testing     
blacka    ab-1    abcd0402    222 22  -222    -22 -222    -22 2   2   Testing
```

I need to pull 3 sets of data from the column "Test1", I am currently using:

```
^(?<testTest1>[^\s]+)*\s*[^\s]*\s*(?<testType1>[^\s]+)\s*(?<testType2>\d+)
```

and the output is:

```
whitea
whiteb
greya
blacka
```

is this possible ONLY using regular expressions? and if so how can i do it?

```
whitea        greya        blacka
whiteb
```

FYI: I am using expresso application for testing, and in design mode at the bottom ignore white, and multiline are checked beyond the standard compiled and culture invariant

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be about splitting one column into three groups. Can you explain better please?

Comment: Where will you actually be using the regex?  In Perl?  I ask because Expresso uses the .NET flavor, which has slightly different syntax and capabilities.

Comment: That is a dreadful regex. The only non-optional components are `(?<testType1>[^\s]+)` and `(?<testType2>\d+)` so the string `*2` will match, assigning `*` to `$2` and `2` to `$3`. You've also used named capture groups which are no advantage for such a simple pattern and only serve to obfuscate the code. Also, `[^\s]` is typically written as `\S`

Comment: @AlanMoore I will be using the .NET flavor, we have a converter i put this into and it pulls data.

Comment: @Borodin yes i would imagine it is, i have been working with regular expressions for less than a week, it currently helps me to name them for understanding. i did not know how that is typically written i will update, thanks for the input.

Comment: If you're using .NET regex, why did you use the perl and pcre tags instead of the .net tag? (As an aside, PCRE is not the same as Perl regex, so if you *are* using Perl regex, you should drop the pcre tag.)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot i updated, thanks for the input

Comment: Sure, no problem. Did you mean to leave the perl tag in?

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand what you want. Your question doesn't appear to be about separating one column into three groups

I wonder if you mean that you want the values of the first column divided into groups according to their value excluding the last character?

This will do that for you

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'max';

<DATA> for 1, 2; # Drop header lines

my %data;
my @groups;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ($test1) = split ' ', $_, 2;
    my $group = substr $test1, 0, -1;
    push @groups, $group unless $data{$group};
    push @{ $data{$group} }, $test1;
}

my $w = max map length, map @$_, values %data;
my $rows = max map { scalar @$_ } values %data;
my $fmt = join(' ', ( "%-${w}s" ) x keys %data) . "\n";

for my $i ( 0 .. $rows-1 ) {
    printf $fmt, map { $_->[$i] // '' } map { $data{$_} } @groups;
}

__DATA__
common: "mortalkombat_sonia_rules_abc," player: "Mortal Kombat,"    22-May-    22 
Test1   Test2   Type1   Type2   Type3   X   Y   HOR1    VER1    Data1         Error1         
Whitea   ab-1    abcr0201    222 22  -222    -22 -222    -22 2   2   Testing     
Whiteb   ab-1    abcr0201    222 22  -222    -22 -222    -22 2   2   Testing     
greya    ab-1    abcf0402    222 2   -222    -22 -222    -22 2   2   Testing     
blacka    ab-1    abcd0402    222 22  -222    -22 -222    -22 2   2   Testing
```

#### output

```
Whitea greya blacka 
Whiteb
```

Comment: yes I am trying to divide the column into groups according to their value, I am sorry if my question was confusing I thought it would be called groups of data. thank you for the help!